# Does the service worker have an "exit" event?

Tags: service-worker, workbox

In the process of operation, the service worker contains a certain amount of data that must be saved before the service worker is completed, as well as it is necessary for monitoring.

How do I find out when the service worker is finished?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "exit" event that gets fired before a service worker thread is terminated. Service workers are expected to be ephemeral, starting up when there's a relevant event and then shutting down shortly after that event has been handled.

The events that can wake up a service worker tend to implement the [`ExtendableEvent` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent), and you can perform asynchronous work inside of an event handler as long as that work is wrapped in a promise which you pass to [`event.waitUntil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil). Each browser has its own time limits on how much time can be spent inside of `waitUntil()` before the service worker thread is unconditionally terminated.

Generally speaking, if you have work you need to perform inside of a service worker, and you want some way of indicating that the work has successfully completed, you're going to want to either use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage) to send a message to one or more open client pages, or write "completion" data to somewhere that's observable from client pages, like IndexedDB or the Cache Storage API.

Comment: We need to save some data on our server before shutting down a service worker, as well as track the life cycle of a service worker to find out how long it lives

Comment: I have reasons to doubt there are events that "wake up" a service worker. When one is activated it _is_ started, but that's a natural coincidence. Starting of a service worker is, however, not activation. Starting and stopping of a service worker does not cause any events to be fired, not in my experience.

Comment: @Jeff Posnick, I need timers running over several days (in a PWA). But according to my tests on Android 13 the service worker is shut down after less than a minute if there are no clients. I guess that people are working on this and would be glad for a link. (And the timers are dropped.)